# Objective-C: Database support

Tags: sql-server, objective-c, database, oracle, database-connection

How can I connect to an Oracle database and SQL Server 2005-2008 database with Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be few Objective-C libraries, probably because you can simply use the already available C libraries in Objective-C.

You can:

- look at [MacSQL Framework](http://www.rtlabs.com/fwork/) (commercial)
- use any of the usual C APIs (and possibly wrap them nicely)
- use any of the C++ abstractions via [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html)